# How to disable pagination dots in Swiper with Center Mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am working with Swiper 6.02 and I am wondering how to get rid of the dots that show the current page. I want to use the "Center" mode, but without the page dots at the bottom. I have tried several suggested solutions, but the only one that has really worked is to disable the "Pagination" option, but that also disables the centering of the slides.

```
            <Swiper
                slidesPerView={1.2}
                centeredSlides={true}
                spaceBetween={30}
                pagination={{
                    clickable: true,
                }}
                className="mySwiper"
            >
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
            </Swiper>
```

Basically I want [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/iplfm) without the pagination dots.

Comment: Remove this `pagination={{clickable: true,}}` from your code (That's it). I didn't find any bug related to disable pagination and center mode (Try swiper 7 maybe).

Answer (score 2):

I used this on the CSS file, and it worked!

```
.swiper-pagination-bullets {
    display: none;
}
```

cheers!

Answer (score -1):

```
<Swiper showsPagination={false} />
```